# Create react app build error "Class constructor Parser cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm-build

im pretty new to react and have wrote an application, the application runs perfectly on the local server yet when i'm trying to build it for production i run into the above error, i cant find any reference to a Parser class, similar questions say that it's to do with an error with Babel trans-piling ES6 classes but i'm using the latest version of CRA and have followed the examples for creating Components on the docs.

The only exception I have to this is that i'm using React-Straps for a Modal component (the only component using this in my application). Can anyone advice on this error (as usually this error throws for hand written components)

EDIT: i tried to create a fresh app and this built successfully

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: I can link to the git repo (if that's what you're asking for) but I cant put my finger on any file in particular that could be causing the problem